# R How to mutate a subset of rows

Tags: r, data.table, subset, dplyr

I am having trouble mutating a subset of rows in `dplyr`.  I am using the chaining command: `%>%` to say:

```
data <- data %>%
  filter(ColA == "ABC") %>%
  mutate(ColB = "XXXX")
```

This works fine but the problems is that I want to be able to select the entire original table and see the mutate applied to only the subset of data I had specified.  My problem is that when I view data after this I only see the subset of `data` and its updated `ColB` information.

I would also like to know how to do this using `data.table`.

Thanks.

Comment: I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/34096575/7662327 gives a comprehensive exploration for modifying selected rows.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using `data.table`, we'd do:

```
setDT(data)[colA == "ABC", ColB := "XXXX"]
```

and the values are modified *in-place*, unlike `if-else`, which'd copy the entire column to replace just those rows where the condition satisfies.

We call this *sub-assign* by reference. You can read more about it in the [new HTML vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).

Comment: Thank you. This worked. And how do I do a mulitple criteria filter? I tried the following but it does not seem to be the correct syntax.`setDT(data)[(colA == "ABC") & (colC =="DEF"), ColB := "XXXX"]`

Comment: @user1991118 that *is* the correct syntax - perhaps you can show a reproducible example. The only thing I can think of is maybe you meant to use `|` instead of `&`.

Comment: That was indeed the correct syntax.  I had used the wrong variable.  It is working.

Answer (score 17):

When you use `filter()` you are actually removing the rows that do not match the condition you specified, so they will not show up in the final data set.

Does `ColB` already exist in your data frame? If so,

```
data %>%
  mutate(ColB = ifelse(ColA == "ABC", "XXXX", ColB))
```

will change `ColB` to `"XXXX"` when `ColA == "ABC"` and leave it as is otherwise. If `ColB` does not already exist, then you will have to specify what to do for rows where `ColA != "ABC"`, for example:

```
data %>%
  mutate(ColB = ifelse(ColA == "ABC", "XXXX", NA))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to perform a subsequent combination of union and anti-join with the same data. This requires a primary key:

```
data <- data %>%
  filter(ColA == "ABC") %>%
  mutate(ColB = "XXXX") %>%
  rbind_list(., anti_join(data, ., by = ...))
```

Example:

```
mtcars_n <- mtcars %>% add_rownames
mtcars_n %>%
  filter(cyl > 6) %>%
  mutate(mpg = 1) %>%
  rbind_list(., anti_join(mtcars_n, ., by = "rowname"))
```

This is much slower than probably any other approach, but useful to get quick results by extending your existing pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Just updating *(by June 02nd 2022)* @krlmlr great answer:

`add_rownames()` is deprecated, use `tibble::rownames_to_column()` instead.
`rbind_list` is also deprecated, use `bind_rows` instead

You might also find a different sequence of rows in your resulting joined dataset, which depending on your aim is quite difficult to correct with `dplyr::arrange()` afterwards.

An alternative, although slower, is:

```
mtcars_n <- mtcars %>% 
  add_rownames() %>% 
  filter(cyl > 6) %>%
  mutate(new_col = 1)
mtcars_m <- left_join(x=mtcars, y=mtcars_n)
```