# dplyr mutate/replace several columns on a subset of rows

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I'm in the process of trying out a dplyr-based workflow (rather than using mostly data.table, which I'm used to), and I've come across a problem that I can't find an equivalent dplyr solution to. I commonly run into the scenario where I need to conditionally update/replace several columns based on a single condition. Here's some example code, with my data.table solution:

```
library(data.table)

# Create some sample data
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(site = sample(1:6, 50, replace=T),
                 space = sample(1:4, 50, replace=T),
                 measure = sample(c('cfl', 'led', 'linear', 'exit'), 50, 
                               replace=T),
                 qty = round(runif(50) * 30),
                 qty.exit = 0,
                 delta.watts = sample(10.5:100.5, 50, replace=T),
                 cf = runif(50))

# Replace the values of several columns for rows where measure is "exit"
dt <- dt[measure == 'exit', 
         `:=`(qty.exit = qty,
              cf = 0,
              delta.watts = 13)]
```

Is there a simple dplyr solution to this same problem? I'd like to avoid using ifelse because I don't want to have to type the condition multiple times - this is a simplified example, but there are sometimes many assignments based on a single condition.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

These solutions (1) maintain the pipeline, (2) do *not* overwrite the input and (3) only require that the condition be specified once:

**1a) mutate_cond** Create a simple function for data frames or data tables that can be incorporated into pipelines.  This function is like `mutate` but only acts on the rows satisfying the condition:

```
mutate_cond <- function(.data, condition, ..., envir = parent.frame()) {
  condition <- eval(substitute(condition), .data, envir)
  .data[condition, ] <- .data[condition, ] %>% mutate(...)
  .data
}

DF %>% mutate_cond(measure == 'exit', qty.exit = qty, cf = 0, delta.watts = 13)
```

**1b) mutate_last** This is an alternative function for data frames or data tables which again is like `mutate` but is only used within `group_by` (as in the example below) and only operates on the last group rather than every group.  Note that TRUE > FALSE so if `group_by` specifies a condition then `mutate_last` will only operate on rows satisfying that condition.

```
mutate_last <- function(.data, ...) {
  n <- n_groups(.data)
  indices <- attr(.data, "indices")[[n]] + 1
  .data[indices, ] <- .data[indices, ] %>% mutate(...)
  .data
}


DF %>% 
   group_by(is.exit = measure == 'exit') %>%
   mutate_last(qty.exit = qty, cf = 0, delta.watts = 13) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   select(-is.exit)
```

**2) factor out condition** Factor out the condition by making it an extra column which is later removed.  Then use `ifelse`, `replace` or arithmetic with logicals as illustrated.  This also works for data tables.

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>% mutate(is.exit = measure == 'exit',
              qty.exit = ifelse(is.exit, qty, qty.exit),
              cf = (!is.exit) * cf,
              delta.watts = replace(delta.watts, is.exit, 13)) %>%
       select(-is.exit)
```

**3) sqldf** We could use SQL `update` via the sqldf package in the pipeline for data frames (but not data tables unless we convert them -- this may represent a bug in dplyr.  See [dplyr issue 1579](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1579)).  It may seem that we are undesirably modifying the input in this code due to the existence of the `update` but in fact the `update` is acting on a copy of the input in the temporarily generated database and not on the actual input.

```
library(sqldf)

DF %>% 
   do(sqldf(c("update '.' 
                 set 'qty.exit' = qty, cf = 0, 'delta.watts' = 13 
                 where measure = 'exit'", 
              "select * from '.'")))
```

**4) row_case_when** Also check out `row_case_when` defined in 
[Returning a tibble: how to vectorize with case_when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837438/returning-a-tibble-how-to-vectorize-with-case-when/61853888?noredirect=1#comment109407490_61853888) .  It uses a syntax similar to `case_when` but applies to rows.

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  row_case_when(
    measure == "exit" ~ data.frame(qty.exit = qty, cf = 0, delta.watts = 13),
    TRUE ~ data.frame(qty.exit, cf, delta.watts)
  )
```

**Note 1:** We used this as `DF`

```
set.seed(1)
DF <- data.frame(site = sample(1:6, 50, replace=T),
                 space = sample(1:4, 50, replace=T),
                 measure = sample(c('cfl', 'led', 'linear', 'exit'), 50, 
                               replace=T),
                 qty = round(runif(50) * 30),
                 qty.exit = 0,
                 delta.watts = sample(10.5:100.5, 50, replace=T),
                 cf = runif(50))
```

**Note 2:** The problem of how to easily specify updating a subset of rows is also discussed in dplyr issues [134](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/134), [631](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/631), [1518](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1518) and [1573](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1573) with [631](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/631) being the main thread and [1573](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1573) being a review of the answers here.

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks! Your mutate_cond and @Kevin Ushey's mutate_when are both good solutions to this problem. I think I have a slight preference for the readability/flexibility of mutate_when, but I'll give this answer the "check" for thoroughness.

Comment: I really like the mutate_cond approach. It seems too me like this function or something very close to it merits inclusion in dplyr and would be a better solution than VectorizedSwitch (that is discussed in https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1573) for the use case that people are thinking about here ...

Comment: I love mutate_cond. The various options should have been separate answers.

Comment: It's been a couple years and the github issues seem closed and locked. Is there an official solution to this problem?

Comment: This is a great solution to the example in the question asked, but it cannot create new rows in the DF. Since there are fewer rows in `.data[condition, ] <- .data[condition, ] %>% mutate(...)` it throws an error `Can't recycle input of size *x* to size *(<x)*.` It would be good to make the rows that don't satisfy the condition as NA if the column doesn't already exist

Comment: But pre-initializing columns with NA constrains the column to be of type `logical`. I don't know of a good way to create a column without declaring its type in a tibble or data.frame

Comment: Amazing any of these has not been implemented in the package, having this post more than 55k views. Default behaviour is a silent, non-intuitive destroyer of rows. Recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 32):

You can do this with `magrittr`'s two-way pipe `%<>%`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

dt[dt$measure=="exit",] %<>% mutate(qty.exit = qty,
                                    cf = 0,  
                                    delta.watts = 13)
```

This reduces the amount of typing, but is still much slower than `data.table`.

Comment: Actually, now that I've had a chance to test this out, I'd prefer a solution that avoids the need to subset using the dt[dt$measure == 'exit', ] notation, since that can get unwieldy with longer dt names.

Comment: Just an FYI, but this solution will only work if the `data.frame` / `tibble` already contains the column defined by `mutate`. It won't work if you are trying to add a new column, e.g., first time running through a loop and modifying a `data.frame`.

Comment: @UrsusFrost adding a new column that is only a subset of the dataset seems weird to me. You add NA to rows that are not subsetted?

Comment: @Baraliuh Yes, I can appreciate that. It's part of a loop in which I increment and append data over a list of dates. The first few dates have to be treated differently than subsequent dates as it is replicating real-world business processes. In further iterations, depending on conditions of the dates, the data is calculated differently. Due to the conditionality, I don't want to inadvertently change previous dates in the `data.frame`. FWIW, I just went back to using `data.table` instead of `dplyr` because its `i` expression handles this easily--plus the overall loop runs much faster.

Answer (score 20):

Here's a solution I like:

```
mutate_when <- function(data, ...) {
  dots <- eval(substitute(alist(...)))
  for (i in seq(1, length(dots), by = 2)) {
    condition <- eval(dots[[i]], envir = data)
    mutations <- eval(dots[[i + 1]], envir = data[condition, , drop = FALSE])
    data[condition, names(mutations)] <- mutations
  }
  data
}
```

It lets you write things like e.g.

```
mtcars %>% mutate_when(
  mpg > 22,    list(cyl = 100),
  disp == 160, list(cyl = 200)
)
```

which is quite readable -- although it may not be as performant as it could be.

Answer (score 15):

As eipi10 shows above, there's not a simple way to do a subset replacement in dplyr because DT uses pass-by-reference semantics vs dplyr using pass-by-value. dplyr requires the use of `ifelse()` on the whole vector, whereas DT will do the subset and update by reference (returning the whole DT). So, for this exercise, DT will be substantially faster.

You could alternatively subset first, then update, and  finally recombine:

```
dt.sub <- dt[dt$measure == "exit",] %>%
  mutate(qty.exit= qty, cf= 0, delta.watts= 13)

dt.new <- rbind(dt.sub, dt[dt$measure != "exit",])
```

But DT is gonna be substantially faster:
(editted to use eipi10's new answer)

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(dt= {dt <- dt[measure == 'exit', 
                            `:=`(qty.exit = qty,
                                 cf = 0,
                                 delta.watts = 13)]},
               eipi10= {dt[dt$measure=="exit",] %<>% mutate(qty.exit = qty,
                                cf = 0,  
                                delta.watts = 13)},
               alex= {dt.sub <- dt[dt$measure == "exit",] %>%
                 mutate(qty.exit= qty, cf= 0, delta.watts= 13)

               dt.new <- rbind(dt.sub, dt[dt$measure != "exit",])})


Unit: microseconds
expr      min        lq      mean   median       uq      max neval cld
     dt  591.480  672.2565  747.0771  743.341  780.973 1837.539   100  a 
 eipi10 3481.212 3677.1685 4008.0314 3796.909 3936.796 6857.509   100   b
   alex 3412.029 3637.6350 3867.0649 3726.204 3936.985 5424.427   100   b
```

Answer (score 10):

I just stumbled across this and really like `mutate_cond()` by @G. Grothendieck, but thought it might come in handy to also handle new variables. So, below has two additions:

Unrelated: Second last line made a bit more `dplyr` by using `filter()`

Three new lines at the beginning get variable names for use in `mutate()`, and initializes any new variables in the data frame before `mutate()` occurs. New variables are initialized for the remainder of the `data.frame` using `new_init`, which is set to missing (`NA`) as a default.

```
mutate_cond <- function(.data, condition, ..., new_init = NA, envir = parent.frame()) {
  # Initialize any new variables as new_init
  new_vars <- substitute(list(...))[-1]
  new_vars %<>% sapply(deparse) %>% names %>% setdiff(names(.data))
  .data[, new_vars] <- new_init

  condition <- eval(substitute(condition), .data, envir)
  .data[condition, ] <- .data %>% filter(condition) %>% mutate(...)
  .data
}
```

Here are some examples using the iris data:

Change `Petal.Length` to 88 where `Species == "setosa"`. This will work in the original function as well as this new version.

```
iris %>% mutate_cond(Species == "setosa", Petal.Length = 88)
```

Same as above, but also create a new variable `x` (`NA` in rows not included in the condition). Not possible before.

```
iris %>% mutate_cond(Species == "setosa", Petal.Length = 88, x = TRUE)
```

Same as above, but rows not included in the condition for `x` are set to FALSE.

```
iris %>% mutate_cond(Species == "setosa", Petal.Length = 88, x = TRUE, new_init = FALSE)
```

This example shows how `new_init` can be set to a `list` to initialize multiple new variables with different values. Here, two new variables are created with excluded rows being initialized using different values (`x` initialised as `FALSE`, `y` as `NA`)

```
iris %>% mutate_cond(Species == "setosa" & Sepal.Length < 5,
                  x = TRUE, y = Sepal.Length ^ 2,
                  new_init = list(FALSE, NA))
```

Comment: Your `mutate_cond` function trows an error on my dataset, and Grothendiecks' function doesn't. `Error: incorrect length (4700), expecting: 168` Seems to be related to the filter function.

Comment: Have you put this into a library or formalized it as a function? It seems like a no-brainer, particularly with all the improvements.

Comment: No. I think best approach with dplyr at this time is to combine mutate with `if_else` or `case_when`.

Comment: Can you provide an example (or link) to this approach?

Answer (score 10):

One concise solution would be to do the mutation on the filtered subset and then add back the non-exit rows of the table:

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>% 
    filter(measure == 'exit') %>%
    mutate(qty.exit = qty, cf = 0, delta.watts = 13) %>%
    rbind(dt %>% filter(measure != 'exit'))
```

Comment: wow this is nice. I never knew that rbind could nest another filter!

Comment: In fact rbind() is not really doing the work there. The expression within the rbind call is just evaluated to become another tibble. So this pattern of doing a small operation or filter on the data works when passing to any function. It gets particularly ugly if you have a larger operation, so it's usually preferable if you are doing a major transformation on the data frame to store it to an intermediate name.

Answer (score 9):

You could split the dataset and do a regular mutate call on the `TRUE` part.

the split can be done with either `dplyr::group_split()` or `base::split()`, I like the base version better here since it preserves names, see the discussion at https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4223 .

```r
df1 <- data.frame(site = sample(1:6, 50, replace=T),
                  space = sample(1:4, 50, replace=T),
                  measure = sample(c('cfl', 'led', 'linear', 'exit'), 50, 
                                   replace=T),
                  qty = round(runif(50) * 30),
                  qty.exit = 0,
                  delta.watts = sample(10.5:100.5, 50, replace=T),
                  cf = runif(50),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)
```

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  group_split(measure == "exit", .keep = FALSE) %>% 
  modify_at(2, ~mutate(.,qty.exit = qty, cf = 0, delta.watts = 13)) %>%
  bind_rows()
#> # A tibble: 50 × 7
#>     site space measure   qty qty.exit delta.watts    cf
#>    <int> <int> <chr>   <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     5     1 linear     22        0       100.  0.126
#>  2     3     3 led        12        0        61.5 0.161
#>  3     6     1 led        26        0        25.5 0.307
#>  4     5     2 cfl        16        0        26.5 0.865
#>  5     6     3 linear     19        0        57.5 0.684
#>  6     1     4 led        12        0        14.5 0.802
#>  7     6     4 led         5        0        90.5 0.547
#>  8     5     4 linear     28        0        54.5 0.171
#>  9     1     2 linear      5        0        24.5 0.775
#> 10     1     2 cfl        24        0        96.5 0.144
#> # … with 40 more rows
```

```
df1 %>%
  split(~measure == "exit") %>% 
  modify_at("TRUE", ~mutate(.,qty.exit = qty, cf = 0, delta.watts = 13)) %>%
  bind_rows()
#>    site space measure qty qty.exit delta.watts          cf
#> 1     5     1  linear  22        0       100.5 0.125646491
#> 2     3     3     led  12        0        61.5 0.160692291
#> 3     6     1     led  26        0        25.5 0.307239765
#> 4     5     2     cfl  16        0        26.5 0.864969074
#> 5     6     3  linear  19        0        57.5 0.683945200
#> 6     1     4     led  12        0        14.5 0.802398642
#> 7     6     4     led   5        0        90.5 0.547211378
#> 8     5     4  linear  28        0        54.5 0.170614207
#> 9     1     2  linear   5        0        24.5 0.774603932
#> 10    1     2     cfl  24        0        96.5 0.144310557
#> 11    3     4  linear  21        0        93.5 0.682622390
#> 12    4     4     led   2        0        48.5 0.941718646
#> 13    4     4     cfl   2        0       100.5 0.918448627
#> 14    5     2     led  11        0        63.5 0.998143780
#> 15    4     1     led  21        0        53.5 0.644740176
#> 16    1     3     cfl   5        0        28.5 0.110610285
#> 17    1     3  linear  24        0        41.5 0.538868200
#> 18    4     3     led  29        0        19.5 0.998474289
#> 19    2     3     cfl   4        0        22.5 0.008167536
#> 20    5     1     led  20        0        56.5 0.740833476
#> 21    3     2     led   5        0        44.5 0.223967706
#> 22    1     4     led  27        0        32.5 0.199850583
#> 23    3     4     cfl  17        0        61.5 0.104023080
#> 24    1     3     cfl  11        0        34.5 0.399036247
#> 25    2     3  linear  29        0        65.5 0.600678235
#> 26    2     4     cfl  23        0        29.5 0.291611352
#> 27    6     2  linear  13        0        37.5 0.225021614
#> 28    2     3     led  17        0        62.5 0.879606956
#> 29    2     4     led  29        0        51.5 0.301759669
#> 30    5     1     led  11        0        54.5 0.793816856
#> 31    2     3     led  20        0        29.5 0.514759195
#> 32    3     4  linear   6        0        68.5 0.475085443
#> 33    1     4     led  21        0        34.5 0.133207588
#> 34    2     4  linear  25        0        80.5 0.164279355
#> 35    5     3     led   7        0        73.5 0.252937836
#> 36    6     2     led  15        0        99.5 0.554864929
#> 37    3     2  linear   6        0        44.5 0.377257874
#> 38    4     4    exit  15       15        13.0 0.000000000
#> 39    3     3    exit  10       10        13.0 0.000000000
#> 40    5     1    exit  15       15        13.0 0.000000000
#> 41    4     2    exit   1        1        13.0 0.000000000
#> 42    5     3    exit  10       10        13.0 0.000000000
#> 43    1     3    exit  14       14        13.0 0.000000000
#> 44    5     2    exit  12       12        13.0 0.000000000
#> 45    2     2    exit  30       30        13.0 0.000000000
#> 46    6     3    exit  28       28        13.0 0.000000000
#> 47    1     1    exit  14       14        13.0 0.000000000
#> 48    3     3    exit  21       21        13.0 0.000000000
#> 49    4     2    exit  13       13        13.0 0.000000000
#> 50    4     3    exit  12       12        13.0 0.000000000
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, this solution is really elegant! One tricky thing (for me) is that the index for `TRUE` is 2, not 1.

Comment: @Yeoman I refreshed my answer, I think you'll like the 2nd solution.

Answer (score 6):

mutate_cond is a great function, but it gives an error if there is an NA in the column(s) used to create the condition. I feel that a conditional mutate should simply leave such rows alone. This matches the behavior of filter(), which returns rows when the condition is TRUE, but omits both rows with FALSE and NA.

With this small change the function works like a charm:

```
mutate_cond <- function(.data, condition, ..., envir = parent.frame()) {
    condition <- eval(substitute(condition), .data, envir)
    condition[is.na(condition)] = FALSE
    .data[condition, ] <- .data[condition, ] %>% mutate(...)
    .data
}
```

Comment: Thanks Magnus! I'm using this to update a table containing actions and timings for all the objects making up an animation. I hit the NA problem because the data is so varied that some actions make no sense for some objects, so I have NAs in those cells. The other mutate_cond's above crashed, but your solution worked like a charm.

Comment: If this is useful to you, this function is available in a smallpackage I wrote, "zulutils". It's not on CRAN but you can install it using remotes::install_github("torfason/zulutils")

Answer (score 5):

I don't actually see any changes to `dplyr` that would make this much easier. `case_when` is great for when there are multiple different conditions and outcomes for one column but it doesn't help for this case where you want to change multiple columns based on one condition. Similarly, `recode` saves typing if you are replacing multiple different values in one column but doesn't help with doing so in multiple columns at once. Finally, `mutate_at` etc. only apply conditions to the column names not the rows in the dataframe. You could potentially write a function for mutate_at that would do it but I can't figure out how you would make it behave differently for different columns.

That said here is how I would approach it using `nest` form `tidyr` and `map` from `purrr`.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

# Create some sample data
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(site = sample(1:6, 50, replace=T),
                 space = sample(1:4, 50, replace=T),
                 measure = sample(c('cfl', 'led', 'linear', 'exit'), 50, 
                                  replace=T),
                 qty = round(runif(50) * 30),
                 qty.exit = 0,
                 delta.watts = sample(10.5:100.5, 50, replace=T),
                 cf = runif(50))

dt2 <- dt %>% 
  nest(-measure) %>% 
  mutate(data = if_else(
    measure == "exit", 
    map(data, function(x) mutate(x, qty.exit = qty, cf = 0, delta.watts = 13)),
    data
  )) %>%
  unnest()
```

Comment: Only thing I'd suggest is to use `nest(-measure)` to avoid the `group_by`

Comment: Edited to reflect @DaveGruenewald suggestion

Answer (score 4):

With the creation of `rlang`, a slightly modified version of Grothendieck's 1a example is possible, eliminating the need for the `envir` argument, as `enquo()` captures the environment that `.p` is created in automatically.

```r
mutate_rows <- function(.data, .p, ...) {
  .p <- rlang::enquo(.p)
  .p_lgl <- rlang::eval_tidy(.p, .data)
  .data[.p_lgl, ] <- .data[.p_lgl, ] %>% mutate(...)
  .data
}

dt %>% mutate_rows(measure == "exit", qty.exit = qty, cf = 0, delta.watts = 13)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this answer has not been mentioned before. It runs almost as fast as the 'default' `data.table`-solution..

Use `base::replace()`

```
df %>% mutate( qty.exit = replace( qty.exit, measure == 'exit', qty[ measure == 'exit'] ),
                          cf = replace( cf, measure == 'exit', 0 ),
                          delta.watts = replace( delta.watts, measure == 'exit', 13 ) )
```

replace recycles the replacement value, so when you want the values of columns `qty` entered into colums `qty.exit`, you have to subset `qty`  as well... hence the `qty[ measure == 'exit']` in the first replacement..

now, you will probably not want to retype the `measure == 'exit'` all the time... so you can create an index-vector containing that selection, and use it in the functions above.

```
#build an index-vector matching the condition
index.v <- which( df$measure == 'exit' )

df %>% mutate( qty.exit = replace( qty.exit, index.v, qty[ index.v] ),
               cf = replace( cf, index.v, 0 ),
               delta.watts = replace( delta.watts, index.v, 13 ) )
```

**benchmarks**

```
# Unit: milliseconds
#         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# data.table   1.005018 1.053370 1.137456 1.112871 1.186228 1.690996   100
# wimpel       1.061052 1.079128 1.218183 1.105037 1.137272 7.390613   100
# wimpel.index 1.043881 1.064818 1.131675 1.085304 1.108502 4.192995   100
```

Answer (score 1):

At the expense of breaking with the usual dplyr syntax, you can use `within` from base:

```
dt %>% within(qty.exit[measure == 'exit'] <- qty[measure == 'exit'],
              delta.watts[measure == 'exit'] <- 13)
```

It seems to integrate well with the pipe, and you can do pretty much anything you want inside it.

Comment: This doesn't work as written because the second assignment doesn't actually happen. But if you do `dt %>% within({
  delta.watts[measure == 'exit'] <- 13 ;
  qty.exit[measure == 'exit'] <- qty[measure == 'exit'] ;
  cf[measure == 'exit'] <- 0
  })` then it does work