# Conditional update similar to SQL

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataframe

```
library(tidyverse)
x <- c(1,2,3,NA,NA,4,5)
y <- c(1,2,3,5,5,4,5)
z <- c(1,1,1,6,7,7,8)
df <- data.frame(x,y,z)

df
   x y z
1  1 1 1
2  2 2 1
3  3 3 1
4 NA 5 6
5 NA 5 7
6  4 4 7
7  5 5 8
```

I would like to update the dataframe according to the following conditions

- If z==1, update to x=1, else leave the current value for x
- If z==1, update to y=2, else leave the current value for y

The following code does the job fine

```
df %>% mutate(x=if_else(z==1,1,x),y=if_else(z==1,2,y))
   x y z
1  1 2 1
2  1 2 1
3  1 2 1
4 NA 5 6
5 NA 5 7
6  4 4 7
7  5 5 8
```

However, I have to add if_else statement for x and y mutate functions. This has the potential to make my code complicated and hard to read. To give you a SQL analogy, consider the following code

```
UPDATE df
SET x= 1, y= 2
WHERE z = 1;
```

I would like to achieve the following:

- Specify the update condition ahead of time, so I don't have to repeat it for every mutate function
- I would like to avoid using data.table or base R. I am using dplyr so I would like to stick to it for consistency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `mutate_cond` posted at [dplyr mutate/replace several columns on a subset of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096162/dplyr-mutate-replace-several-columns-on-a-subset-of-rows/34096575#34096575) we can do this:

```
df %>% mutate_cond(z == 1, x = 1, y = 2)
```

giving:

```
   x y z
1  1 2 1
2  1 2 1
3  1 2 1
4 NA 5 6
5 NA 5 7
6  4 4 7
7  5 5 8
```

### sqldf

Of course you can directly implement it in SQL with sqldf -- ignore the warning message that the backend RSQLite issues.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf(c("update df set x = 1, y = 2 where z = 1", "select * from df"))
```

### base R

It straight-forward in base R:

```
df[df$z == 1, c("x", "y")] <- list(1, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to mutate_cond. I do hope it gets included in dplyr!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `map2`.  Loop through the 'x', 'y' columns of the dataset, along with the values to change, apply `case_when` based on the values of 'z' if it is TRUE, then return the new value, or else return the same column and `bind` the columns with the original dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map2_df(df %>%
          select(x, y), c(1, 2), ~ case_when(df$z == 1 ~ .y, TRUE ~ .x)) %>%
     bind_cols(df %>%
                 select(z), .) %>%
     select(names(df))
```

---

Or using `base R`, create a logical vector, use that to subset the rows of columns 'x', 'y' and update by assigning to a `list` of values

```
i1 <- df$z == 1
df[i1, c('x', 'y')] <- list(1, 2)
df
#   x y z
#1  1 2 1
#2  1 2 1
#3  1 2 1
#4 NA 5 6
#5 NA 5 7
#6  4 4 7
#7  5 5 8
```

The advantage of both the solutions are that we can pass `n` number of columns with corresponding values to pass and not repeating the code

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(x = replace(x, z == 1, 1),
           y = replace(y, z == 1, 2))
#   x y z
#1  1 2 1
#2  1 2 1
#3  1 2 1
#4 NA 5 6
#5 NA 5 7
#6  4 4 7
#7  5 5 8
```

In base R

```
transform(df,
          x = replace(x, z == 1, 1),
          y = replace(y, z == 1, 2))
```

If you store the condition in a variable, you don't have to type it multiple times

```
condn = (df$z == 1)
transform(df,
          x = replace(x, condn, 1),
          y = replace(y, condn, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an SQL background, you should really check out [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)

set(dt, which(z == 1), c('x', 'y'), list(1, 2))
dt

# or perhaps more classic syntax

dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt
#    x y z
#1:  1 1 1
#2:  2 2 1
#3:  3 3 1
#4: NA 5 6
#5: NA 5 7
#6:  4 4 7
#7:  5 5 8

dt[z == 1, `:=`(x = 1, y = 2)]
dt

#    x y z
#1:  1 2 1
#2:  1 2 1
#3:  1 2 1
#4: NA 5 6
#5: NA 5 7
#6:  4 4 7
#7:  5 5 8
```

The last option is an update join. This is great if you have the lookup data already done upfront:

```
# update join:
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt_lookup <- data.table(x = 1, y = 2, z = 1)

dt[dt_lookup, on = .(z), `:=`(x = i.x, y = i.y)]
dt
```