# Replacing the text of character variable by another text

Tags: r, string, character

I have a dataframe with 2 columns (2 variables). One is a chracter variable, the name of the author, and the other the frequency of the articles of the corresponding author.

There is a mismatch across author names. In particular, one of them appears as Rodriguez A, and other Rodriguez AR, but both are the same person

```
AU                    frequency
Rodriguez AR            20
Rodriguez A              7
```

The idea is to consider all Rodriguez AR, for that reason I coded

```r
authortable$AU <- str_replace_all(authortable$AU, "Rodriguez A", "Rodriguez AR")
```

But there are no changes in the datraframe.
Any suggestions

What I would like to get is

```
AU                    frequency
Rodriguez AR            27
```

Answer (score 3):

**1)** Perform the replacement and then `summarize`:

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
  mutate(AU = sub("^Rodriguez A$", "Rodriguez AR", AU)) %>%
  summarize(frequency = sum(frequency), .by = AU)
##             AU frequency
## 1 Rodriguez AR        27
```

**2)** Another possibility is to use `mutate_cond` defined in [dplyr mutate/replace several columns on a subset of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096162/dplyr-mutate-replace-several-columns-on-a-subset-of-rows/34096575#34096575) .  Here the first argument is a data frame and the second a condition such that the assignment(s) in subsequent argument(s) are only applied to those rows for which that condition holds.

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
  mutate_cond(AU == "Rodriguez A", AU = "Rodriguez AR") %>%
  summarize(frequency = sum(frequency), .by = AU)
##             AU frequency
## 1 Rodriguez AR        27
```

**3)** Another variation is to use `within` and `aggregate` .  this uses only base R.

```
DF |>
  within(AU[AU == "Rodriguez A"] <- "Rodriguez AR") |>
  aggregate(frequency ~ AU, data = _, sum)
##             AU frequency
## 1 Rodriguez AR        27
```

### Note

```
DF <- data.frame(AU = c("Rodriguez AR", "Rodriguez A"), frequency = c(20L, 7L))
```

Comment: This is nice and compact.  I think mine is the only answer that **explains** why the OP was having trouble (i.e., they need to use at least `$` to match end-of-string, or do something to match full words ...)

Answer (score 1):

```r
authortable <- data.frame(AU = rep(c("Rodriguez A", "Rodriguez AR"), c(7, 20)))
authortable |> dplyr::count(AU)
##             AU  n
## 1  Rodriguez A  7
## 2 Rodriguez AR 20
```

If you use your proposed solution you can see that the data frame **does** change, but not in the way you intended:

```r
authortable$AU <- stringr::str_replace_all(authortable$AU, "Rodriguez A", "Rodriguez AR")
authortable |> dplyr::count(AU)
##              AU  n
## 1  Rodriguez AR  7
## 2 Rodriguez ARR 20
```

in other words, this changed "Rodriguez A" to "Rodriguez AR" and "Rodriguez AR" to "Rodriguez ARR".

Going back to the original data frame, one possibility is to use the `^` (beginning-of-string) and `$` (end-of-string) characters to indicate that you only want to change the *complete* string "Rodriguez A" (in this case it's really only the `$` that matters ...)

```r
authortable$AU <- stringr::str_replace_all(authortable$AU, "^Rodriguez A$", "Rodriguez AR")
authortable |> dplyr::count(AU)
##            AU  n
## 1 Rodriguez AR 27
```

If you have a lot of this kind of data cleaning to do you might want to take a look at [Open Refine](https://openrefine.org/).

Answer (score 1):

To replace `"Rodriguez A"` to `"Rodriguez AR"` and get the whole data you could use `mutate()` and call `str_replace_all()` then `summarize()` by `AU` to combine frequency:

```
authortable %>% mutate(AU=str_replace_all(AU, pattern="^Rodriguez A$", replace="Rodriguez AR")) %>%
group_by(AU) %>% summarise(frequency=sum(frequency, na.rm=T))


  AU           frequency
  <chr>            <int>
 Rodriguez AR        27
```

you could also match the start and end of your string using boundary `\\b` as what the `^` and `$` does:

```
authortable %>% mutate(AU=str_replace_all(AU, pattern="\\bRodriguez A\\b", replace="Rodriguez AR")) %>%
group_by(AU) %>% summarise(frequency=sum(frequency, na.rm=T))

  AU           frequency
  <chr>            <int>
 Rodriguez AR        27
```

if not sure about number of `space character between first and last name` you may indicate quantity of spaces using escape character `\\s*` between first and last name :

```
authortable %>% mutate(AU=str_replace_all(AU, pattern="^Rodriguez\\s*A$", replace="Rodriguez AR")) %>%
    group_by(AU) %>% summarise(frequency=sum(frequency, na.rm=T))

  AU           frequency
  <chr>            <int>
 Rodriguez AR        27
```

***details:***

```
^ : starts with
$ : ends with
* : 0 or more (in this case, spaces number)
```

Comment: I do no get the result authortable %>% mutate(AU=str_replace_all(AU, pattern="^Asongu\\s*A$", replace="Asongu SA")) %>%   group_by(AU) %>% summarise(frequency=sum(Freq, na.rm=T)) %>%   top_n(10)
Selecting by frequency
# A tibble: 15 × 2
   AU         frequency
   <chr>          <int>
 1 ANDRÉS AR          9
 2 ARLI D             8
 3 ASONGU S           7
 4 ASONGU SA         20
 5 GOPAL RD           8

Answer (score 1):

We can also match on strings, but replace the whole values, not just the substrings. For that, we can use `replace()` or `case_when()` or `case_match()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

authortable <- 
    authortable |>
    mutate(AU = replace(AU, str_detect(AU, "Rodriguez A"), "Rodriguez AR"))
```

Then just do whatever downstream analysis we need, such as `count()`