How to update a dataframe based on a condition on the line number
Let's take the mpg file and add an ID as rownumber
DATA1 <- mpg
DATA2 <- dplyr::mutate(DATA1, ID = row_number())

I want to update DATA2 based on the ID for some columns only
IF ID==1 then manufacturer="Honda", cyl=6, year=2005,
IF ID==2 then manufacturer="Toyota", class="sedan"

etc.
I have tried the following but it is wordy and does not suit large databases if the patch goes over multiple lines
DATA3 <- DATA2 %>%
  mutate(manufacturer = ifelse(ID == 1, "Honda", manufacturer))  %>% 
  mutate(cyl = ifelse(ID == 1, 6, cyl)) %>%
  mutate(year = ifelse(ID == 1, 2005, year))
DATA3 <- DATA2 %>%
  mutate(manufacturer = ifelse(ID == 2, "Toyota", manufacturer))  %>%
  mutate(class = ifelse(ID == 2, "sedan", class)) 


See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096162/dplyr-mutate-replace-several-columns-on-a-subset-of-rows

Maybe the case_when can help you
mpg %>% 
  mutate(
    id = row_number(),
    manufacturer = case_when(
      id == 1 ~ "Honda",
      id == 2 ~ "Toyota",
      TRUE ~ manufacturer
    ),
    cyl = case_when(
      id == 1 ~ 6,
      TRUE ~ cyl
    ),
    year = case_when(
      id == 1 ~ 2005,
      TRUE ~ year
    ),
    class = case_when(
      id == 2 ~ "Sedan",
      TRUE ~ class
    )
  )

