# Mutate subset of rows by using corresponding values from a different data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two data frames. One contains some towns' names and IDs, the other contains some towns' names and IDs plus an extra value:

```
library(tidyverse)

towns.df <- structure(list(town_id = c(1, 2, 3), town_name = c("Rome", "Madrid", "Sarajevo")),
                      row.names = c(NA, -3L),
                      class = "data.frame") %>% as_tibble()

values.df <- structure(list(town_id = c(1, 5, 4), town_name = c("Rome", "Sarajevo", "Madrid"), town_value = c(18, 11, 15)),
                       row.names = c(NA, -3L),
                       class = "data.frame") %>% as_tibble()
```

The data looks like this:

```
> towns.df
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  town_id town_name
    <dbl> <chr>    
1       1 Rome     
2       2 Madrid   
3       3 Sarajevo

> values.df
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  town_id town_name town_value
    <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>
1       1 Rome              18
2       5 Sarajevo          11
3       4 Madrid            15
```

Using a `tidyverse` solution, I want to join the data frames based on IDs (for separate reasons I **cannot** directly do it based on towns' names) but the problem is that the IDs do not always correspond. The IDs that get priority are those found in `towns.df`, e.g. if the same town has two different IDs in the two data frames, I want it to eventually be associated to the one from `towns.df`.

So I first check what IDs from `towns.df` are not present in `values.df` by using `anti_join()`:

```
> anti_join(towns.df, values.df, "town_id")
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  town_id town_name
    <dbl> <chr>    
1       2 Madrid   
2       3 Sarajevo
```

Then I want to take the corresponding towns and be able to modify `values.df$town_id` accordingly, so that the ID would be the one displayed in `towns.df`.

Or better, I want to directly create a joint data frame where I have `town_id`, `town_name` and `town_value` as columns and with the correct `town_id`.

The desired output is:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  town_id town_name town_value
    <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>
1       1 Rome              18
2       2 Madrid            15
3       3 Sarajevo          11
```

I am aware that in this example the desired output could be obtained by joining the data frames based on `town_name` - i.e. this would do the trick:

```
left_join(towns.df, values.df[,2:3], "town_name")
```

but, as I said, this is something I am not able to do due to separate reasons that are exogenous to this question.

I checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29836123/12391423) but I am not looking to using `mutate` with a literal value, instead I need to use a different column (i.e. `town_id`) than the one I am using to check the identity (i.e. `town_name`).

Answer (score 1):

We may use

```
library(powerjoin)
power_left_join(towns.df, values.df, by = "town_name",  conflict = \(x, y) x)
```